# Hide div on responsive screens

Tags: html, css, facebook-like, responsive

I want to hide the facebook like box with CSS.
I used this:

```
.fb-like-iframe.fb_iframe_widget {
    display: none !important;
}
```

but this works but only for big displays and it's still showing on mobile.

When I resize the webpage on desktop and make it smaller in width, there is a tipping point where the responsive changes and the `fb-like-iframe` is displayed.

I tried using this to hide it on mobile as well but no success do far:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
   .fb-like-iframe.fb_iframe_widget {
      display: none !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we see where this is in situ, ie, post a url where the code is please so we can inspect it. My gut feeling is to put this widget into an enclosing div and then show or hide that div depending on viewport width media query.

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.quizuri.ro/quizzes/cate-patrate-sunt-in-imagine/1026?embed=true just click start and select any answer . After that wait a few seconds for the modal to pop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` you can use `min-width` and `max-width`.
Or better result you can use only `max-width`..

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen (max-width : 480px) {
  .fb-like-iframe.fb_iframe_widget {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek Pandey , Yes I agree with you but OP can define max-width according his requirement. i just tell them what he did wrong.

Comment: I've also tried that and it doesn't work. Here is the link: quizuri.ro/quizzes/cate-patrate-sunt-in-imagine/1026?embed=t‌​rue just click start and select any answer . After that wait a few seconds for the modal to pop.

Answer (score 0):

currently you are using this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.fb-like-iframe.fb_iframe_widget {
    display: none !important;
}
```

just change `(min-width: 768px)` to `(max-width: 768px)`
let me know if this is what you need

Comment: I've tried that as well, no luck. You can see here: http://www.quizuri.ro/quizzes/cate-patrate-sunt-in-imagine/1026?embed=true

Comment: can you screenshot what is the exact thing you want to hide ?

Comment: here are the screenshots http://i.imgur.com/IoWiSBT.png (mobile)  http://i.imgur.com/EirOWHe.png (desktop) I've also made a video showing the responsive tipping point from desktop to mobile https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpUONG6MGfE

Comment: my friend my solution worked correctly for me, just check if there is syntax errors or typo issues, you can find the style in your style.css at line:183 just change `min` to `max`

Comment: Yes I've changed the code as you said but still not working. Here is the code http://i.imgur.com/dre8gPn.png

Comment: that's really weird ! I don't know why it's not working with you, try making it `@media (max-width: 768px){.fb-like-iframe.fb_iframe_widget {display: none !important;}}` and also put this line at the bottom of your css stylesheet so it will override if there is something affecting it

Comment: I've added the `@media (max-width: 768px){.fb-like-iframe.fb_iframe_widget {display: none !important;}}` at the buttom, but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

There was conflict of style.css with a minified version that was causing it not to work only on mobile.

```css
.fb-like-iframe.fb_iframe_widget {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I've fixed it and now the original code (above) works on both desktop and mobile. Thanks